# wordpress get post content with ajax after jquery animation?

Tags: jquery, ajax

i wanna get the post content after jquery animation with ajax, like the jpg flow..!
[the plan wrote in image](http://img4host.net/upload/3003324151088649d5f2d.jpg)

this is the jquery code now i have :

```
 $(".read-more").click(function() {
   var wheight = $(window).height() 

   $("#wrapper").animate({top:wheight},700,'easeInOutQuart', function(){
       $("#wrapper_project").slideDown('1000','easeOutCirc');
       $("#menu").fadeOut('500');

});

});
```

this is the HTML template :

```
<section class="block">

             <?php
                $mypost = array( 
                'post_type' => 'project',
                'posts_per_page' => 1000,
                );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );
                ?>

             <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>

             <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('post clearfix'); ?>>
                <div class="left thumbnail_box">    
                    <a rel="<?php the_permalink() ?>" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'project-thumbnail' ); ?></a>
                </div>
                 <div class="desc">
                    <h3 class="post_title"><a rel="<?php the_permalink() ?>" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <p class="entry-content"><?php the_content(); ?> <a rel="<?php the_permalink() ?>" href="#" class="read-more">...Read More</a> </p>
                 </div>
             </article>


             <?php endwhile; ?>
             <!-- list_view-->

             <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>


         </section><!-- section -->
```

Comment: Where's the ajax? I just see the animation.

Comment: Ya..i need add ajax function in this animation.